# Why I can't dispatch multiple action with a map?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I am trying to understand something Inside my epic

```
const loginEpic = (action$, state$) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(UsersActions.loginRequest),
    switchMap((action: {payload:{email: string, password: string}}) => 
        HttpService.PostAsync<apiModels.api_token_auth_request, apiModels.api_token_auth_response>('token-auth', action.payload).pipe(
            switchMap(response => {
                let token = response && response.data && response.data.token ? response.data.token : '';
                return of(
                    UsersActions.setUserAuth({authKey: token}),
                    UsersActions.loginSuccess(),
                    WorkspaceActions.getWorkspacesRequest()
                );
            }),
            catchError((error: string) => {
                return of(UsersActions.loginFailed({error}));
            })
        )
    )
);
```

Why this works

```
switchMap(response => {
    let token = response && response.data && response.data.token ? response.data.token : '';
    return of(
        UsersActions.setUserAuth({authKey: token}),
        UsersActions.loginSuccess(),
        WorkspaceActions.getWorkspacesRequest()
    );
}),
```

But this will not work

```
map(response => {
    let token = response && response.data && response.data.token ? response.data.token : '';
    return concat(
        of(UsersActions.setUserAuth({authKey: token})),
        of(UsersActions.loginSuccess()),
        of(WorkspaceActions.getWorkspacesRequest())
    );
}),
```

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware
>   for async actions.

Isn't the second one also a first stream ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switchMap` will subscribe to the inner Observable returned (in this case `of`) and reemit all its items. So `of` emits 3 items that are propagated further.

On the other hand, `map` just takes the value returned from its "project" function and propagates it further. `map` doesn't care what the returned value is. No further logic is applied.

So in your case `map` is propagating an instance of Observable which is not a valid action.